# Converting Pandas Series from groupby result to numpy array or to list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas data frame as below:

```
data = 
   grouping  cols1
       1     10
       1      5
       2     30
       2     10
       3     35
```

I conducted a groupby operation:

```
df = data.groupby('grouping')['cols1'].apply(lambda x: np.where(np.sum(x)>0, np.sum(x),0))

grouping
1                    25
2                    40
3                    35
Name: cols1, dtype: object
```

I would like to convert df (from groupby operation) to numpy array or to list that results as:

```
array([25,40,35])
```

and

```
[25,40,35]
```

I tried: df.to_numpy() and df.tolist(). But the result is not right as below:

```
array([array(25), array(40), array(35)], dtype=object)
```

and

```
[array(25),
 array(40),
 array(35)]
```

Any way to solve this?

Comment: Use [`Series.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html) ?

Comment: Same result: array([array(25), array(40), array(35)])

Comment: which pandas version are you using ? And can you share your group operation ?

Comment: 1.1.3 pandas version

Comment: How did you reach this data ? Can you share your `groupby` code ?

Comment: You are having this issue here because you returned a numpy scalar array in your aggregate function with `np.where`. You don't need `np.where` here for your case. Just do `df.groupby('grouping')['cols1'].apply(lambda x: max(x.sum(), 0))`. And then it should work as expected.

Comment: You are correct. I adjust my groupby() operation and it now works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```py
np.array(df["<column_name>"].values)
```

should output your desired array

Answer (score 0):

You can try using list comprehension:

```
# Create your input series
s = pd.Series([np.array(25), np.array(40), np.array(35)], index=[1,2,3], name='cols1')
[i.tolist() for i in s]
```

Output:

```
[25, 40, 35]
```

Note:  I would like to see the code you used to generate this pd.Series  I suspect, we might be able to avoid this problem in that code.

---

```
s.map(lambda x: x.tolist()).to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
array([25, 40, 35], dtype=int64)
```